# Winston Julia - WARNING: deprecated syntax

Tags: plot, julia, winston

I am trying to use the Winston graphing package.  When I do so, I get the following warnings:

```
using Winston

Winston.plot(x -> sin(x)*x,0,2)
Winston.grid()

WARNING: deprecated syntax "AbstractVecOrMat{T} (" at /home/jmarcellopereira/.julia/v0.4/Winston/src/Winston.jl:96.
Use "AbstractVecOrMat{T}(" instead.
WARNING: requiring "Dates" in module "Winston" did not define a corresponding module.
WARNING: module Winston should explicitly import * from Base
WARNING: both Winston and SymPy export "Curve"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
```

What do these mean and will they prevent my plot from being generated?

Comment: It looks like Winston has not been updated in a while, why don't you try a different plotting package, e.g. Plots.jl? In any case, this is only a warning, not actually an error.

Answer (score 2):

The above code that you use still works fine on my computer (using Julia 0.4.6).  The warnings are just because Winston hasn't been updated recently.  Since its last update, the underlying Julia code has changed and Winston hasn't fully adapted to incorporate these changes.  There's nothing that you can do to "fix" these warnings, unless you want to volunteer to help with the development of the Winston package.

In this case though, these issues don't prevent you from accomplishing the plot that you want, but they warn you that you may encounter problems in other settings.